# WordPress Multiple Loop: Home/Archives Page, with pagination

Tags: loop

I can not write English, and I'm using the google translator.
I believe that pictures can say more than words. Please watch this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99YKW.jpg

is possible to do something? Please, help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the picture does not explain the problem. I can't tell what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The codex explains how you could achieve multiple loops on one page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

You could use categories in `$query_args` to separate out the different loops for the design you have.